# django urls.py: two modules with similar paths

Tags: django, django-urls

I have two modules in my django app, let's say `cats` and `dogs`, and I want to have urls like this:

- `/fluffy/meow.html`  - Fluffy is a cat's name
- `/fluffy/eat.html`
- `/jackie/bark.html`  - Jackie is a dog
- `/jackie/eat.html`   - same name as in cats module

There will be a lot of different cats and dogs, but it's guaranteed, that cat and dog can't have the same name.

If I make `urls.py` like this:

```py
urlpatterns += [
    path('<slug:cat_name>/', include('cats.urls')),
    path('<slug:dog_name>/', include('dogs.urls')),
]
```

request `/jackie/eat.html` wil be caught by `cats`
module, but there's no cat with name jackie, so it will give 404 error. Is it possible to make django check another url path instead of getting 404 error?

---

I know, that I can use this `urls.py`

```py
urlpatterns += [
    path('cats/<slug:cat_name>/', include('cats.urls')),
    path('dogs/<slug:dog_name>/', include('dogs.urls')),
]
```

But I don't want it

---

there's about 1000 cats' names, and it's not frequently changing, so i can hardcode cat's names in huge `re_path`, but I hope that there's a better solution

```
urlpatterns += [
    re_path(r'^(?P<cat_name>fluffy|simon|thomas|etc..)/$', include('cats.urls')),
    path('<slug:dog_name>/', include('dogs.urls')),
]
```

Comment: I really like this question, and I think there should be an answer. Especially different from the ones below.

Answer (score 0):

No. Change your logic instead of hard cording urls and searching in Urls. 
First categorized your cats and dogs urls then search in db to show them into urls.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, create a model name animal, It contains

```
1. Category - Dog or cat
2. Name - animal name
3. ... if u want any values, add it here
```

for example:

```
from django.db import models

class Animal(models.Model):
    ANIMAL_CHOICES= (
        ('cat', 'cat'),
        ('dog', 'dog'),
    )
    category = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ANIMAL_CHOICES)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

and then in your urls.py

```
urlpatterns += [
    path('cats/<slug:cat_name>/', cat, name="cats"),
    path('dogs/<slug:dog_name>/', dog, name="dogs"),
]
```

In your views.py

```
def cat(request, cat_name):
    cat = Animals.objects.filter(category="cat", name=cat_name)
    context = { cat: cat }
    return render(request, "template_name.html", context=context)

def dog(request, dog_name):
    cat = Animals.objects.filter(category="dog", name=dog_name)
    context = { dog: dog }
    return render(request, "template_name.html", context=context)
```